# How to set Block Class and Template for a Category in Magento via the Admin Panel using XML

Tags: magento, templates, block, categories, magento-1.6

I am trying to override the default template and block class for a particular category in Magento.

The following code ONLY changes the template,

```
<reference name="product_list">
  <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/product/list-foobar.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

I also need to change the default Block Class from Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List to Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Foobar.

Is this possible using XML in "Custom Layout Update" field for a Category?

I have tried the following and it also does NOT work,

```
<reference name="product_list">
  <block type="catalog/product_list_foobar" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list-foobar.phtml" />
</reference>
```

Answer (score 1):

Strictly answered:

```
<CUSTOM_CATEGORY_DISPLAY>
    <reference name="category.products">
        <action method="unsetChild"><child>product_list</child></action>
        <block type="catalog/product_list_foobar" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list-foobar.phtml" />
    </reference>
</CUSTOM_CATEGORY_DISPLAY>
```

Then, you can use `<update handle="CUSTOM_CATEGORY_DISPLAY" />` in the custom Layout Update XML field of each category for which you wish to apply these directives.

But, there is some bizarre/unfortunate coupling between models and blocks involved in layered navigation, so there could very well be some buggy behavior.